# How do I make a List of controls which are clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been unsuccessfully trying to make a List which contains 3 picturebox controls(picturebox1, 2 & 3); and the list needs to have a 2nd argument of true or false. If one picturebox is clicked, the bool is True, and the others are False. The List should look similar to this:

```
pictureBox2, true

pictureBox1, false

pictureBox3, false
```

Now when I push a button I would like the clicked pictureBox to be on the bottom of the list.
And I've been trying to code this so that only the pictureboxes which are false get drawn to the panel. So this means that 'pictureBox1 gets drawn 1st, then pictureBox3.

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(< pictureBox >!true, new Rectangle(< pictureBox >!true.Location, < pictureBox >!true.Size));
```

I don't have the slightest clue to write the List or the paint method. Help would be **very happily** appreciated.

Comment: I'm dreadfully curious about that code... `!true` - Wouldn't this be better represented as `false`?  `!true.Size` - What on Earth is this?

Comment: Dude, I'm unable to figure out if this "list" is just at code or if you want to draw these images... Could you explain a little better? What have you done, so far?

Comment: Yes it is just a hypothetical example David. It doesn't make sense. The actual way to code this is what I am confused about.

Comment: Andre I want to draw the background images of the controls which are false. And the list is for arranging the ORDER of the draw to the panel. I hope I explained better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paint method should go something like this:

```
int Y = 0;
foreach(PictureBox pb in MyList)
{
    if(!pb.Visible)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(pb.BackgroundImage, new Point(0,Y));
        Y += pb.Height;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alex I need to paint the pictureBoxes to the panel when they are not visible. This method would work but I can't use it for my application. I need a list

Comment: Yes Alex. When I click a pictureBox, the other pictureboxes become Invisible & get drawn to the panel. But they only get drawn in 1 way. if(pictureBox1.Visible = false){e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(pictureBox1.Location, pictureBox1.Size));} then if pictureBox2 is invisible it gets drawn. See it gets drawn from 1st to last, but if I change the order that draw order doesn't change.

Comment: I hope the above comment wasn't as confusing as it sounds lol

Comment: @kev You need to do your own layout and not use the PB's location. I changed the code to paint the images in the order they appear in MyList starting at Y=0 and moving down the height of the PB.

Comment: Thanks AlexDev. I know I must've been confusing as heck earlier. Should the list code look something like this?: List<PictureBox> MyList = new List<PictureBox>();
            MyList.Add(pictureBox1);
            MyList.Add(pictureBox2);
            MyList.Add(pictureBox3);

Comment: Yes, or a shorter version would be:List<PictureBox> MyList = new List<PictureBox>(pictureBox1,pictureBox2,pictureBox3); If you want to move a PB to the bottom: MyList.Remove(PB);MyList.Add(PB);panel.Update(); Don't forget to update the panel.

Comment: Thanks AlexDev, you've been a great help A+. but for some reason the Paint method you provided me with would not run. The paint code you provided me with says "Graphics.DrawImage has some invalid arguments"

Comment: oops, the arguments were reversed.

Comment: Yes I see it now, the arguments in the DrawImage was reversed. Thanks